# Shelving code workflow - can I safely undue my changes after shelving them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Once I create a shelve from files in my pending changes, can I then safely undue my changes and continue working and then unshelve at a later date?

What is the correct workflow when shelving?

Comment: I don't know which source version you're using, but you can always list the shelvesets to check. VSTS is in Team Explorer -> Source Control Explorer -> Right click in a folder -> Find -> Find Shelvesets.
But yes, is the shelveset was correctly uploaded, you can undo your changes and unshelve it later.

Comment: Consider that one of the *options* when [shelving](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404(v=vs.100).aspx) is to "Preserve pending change locally". You can choose whether you want the local changes to remain or be reverted *as part* of the Shelve operation.

Comment: It depends. If you will continue to work on the same task and are shelving for back-up purposes, you just shelve and check the "Preserve pending changes locally" check box to keep the files checked out.

Comment: If you will switch to another task (will work on other files) then uncheck the chekbox and you can at any time unshelve your changes to continue.

Comment: Shelve, like Check-in, keeps track of the version you started working on the files. Conflicts caused by other users' commits (check-ins) can be resolved by issuing a get (Get Latest), or you can keep working on your files and can prefer to resolve the conflict when you decide to check-in

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in TFS you can shelve a set of changes and then undo them locally. You can then unshelve your changes later on and those shelved changes will be applied to your local files.

**HOWEVER**, if you shelve-->undo local changes-->change the same files you shelved-->then try to unshelve (before checking in your latest changes)...TFS  won't unshelve due to conflicts because TFS unshelve command doesn't handle conflicts/merging. The good news is you can use TFS Power Tools to unshelve and merge conflicting changes in one step.

This link has a pretty good explanation of unshelving conflicts and how TFS Power Tools can be used for unshelving when there are conflicts: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/12/02/tfs-pills-merging-conflicts-during-unshelve/